# Can Twisted Library be used for a LAN Messenger Development?

Tags: python, udp, twisted, lan, messenger

I am trying to develop a simple LAN Messenger which discovers other clients on the network and helps communicate with them.

Can I use twisted Library to achieve that???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.  Although the body of this answer needs to be at least 30 characters, so yes.